# xmlrpc.php?rsd - what its actually meant by referred in link tag

Tags: php, html

Need definition of this link tag

```
<link rel="EditURI" type="application/rsd+xml" title="RSD" href="xmlrpc.php?rsd">
```

Answer (score 4):

RSD is Really Simple Discovery

the spec can be found here:
[RSD SPEC](http://cyber.law.harvard.edu/blogs/gems/tech/rsd.html)

What it says is: Really Simple Discovery is a way to help client software find the services needed to read, edit, or "work with" weblogging software.